# Put text at given a page number

Tags: page-numbering, page

Is there any easy way to insert some text at a given page number? I could manually trace the page and write something there, but looking for a geeky solution. I am not worried about the position of the text, just accessing the page would work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]

%%%%%%%% Write `Some garbage text` at page 3
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want it written within the text block, in the header/footer, or outside the text block?

Comment: Your solution is fine for me at the moment. Would appreciate, however, if you could describe the individual cases that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to place some text at some random location on page 3, here's an option using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{% Place something in the page ForeGround...
  \AtTextUpperLeft{% ...at the text block upper left corner...
    \ifnum\value{page}=3 % ...only on page 3...
      \makebox[\textwidth]{% ...in the horizontal centre of the text block...
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-.5\textheight}{% ...at the vertical centre of the text block
          \Huge RaNDoM TeXT
        }%
      }%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```